# Python Mocking not returning mocked value for a function

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to write an unit test case using mocking functionality to mock a function.

But the function returns the actual value instead of mocked value.

Here is my sample code,

```
def k_urandom(length):
    return 'k' * length

def abck_urandom(length):
    return 'abc' + k_urandom(length)

class TestRandom(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('demo.k_urandom', return_value='pump')
    def test_urandom(self, k_urandom_function):
        print(abck_urandom(5))
        assert abck_urandom(5) == 'abcpump'
```

While printing the function I got output as `abckkkkk` but what I need is the mocked output that is `abcpump`.

I am using python 3.6.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you running your unittests? Your patch won't work if you execute the file directly.

Comment: @Rawing I am using pydev and running by 'run as python unit test'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed the package name ,

```
@mock.patch('unit_test_example.demo.k_urandom', return_value='pump')
```

Now it's working.